# Django on heroku DEBUG settings

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am a bit confused about the settings for django.

I have something like this setup in my settings.py file locally:

```
"""
Django settings for ebportfolio project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

import environ

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
environ.Env.read_env()
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = environ.Path(__file__)-1
# BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'my heroku address']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cloudinary',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'django_summernote',
    'projects',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ebportfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['ebportfolio/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ebportfolio.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    'default': env.db(),
    # read os.environ['SQLITE_URL']
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

public_root = BASE_DIR.path('')
MEDIA_ROOT = public_root('media')
MEDIA_URL = env.str('MEDIA_URL', default='media/')
STATIC_ROOT = public_root('staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = env.str('STATIC_URL', default='staticfiles/')

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
# Configure Django App for Heroku.
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ='ebportfolio.settings'
import django_heroku

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

With the DEBUG=on in my .env file DEBUG=True, the images show both online and locally. When I switch DEBUG=off in .env the images don't show up running locally. Can someone explain to me why? Is DEBUG influencing where the files are showing from?

Edit whilst writing the post - I changed my heroku URL in allowed hosts to include https:// and now the images show. What documentation shall I look into to understand this?

Answer (score 2):

Because `off` is treated as a string and a non empty string is still truthy

You need to remove `DEBUG` from the env file altogether for it to be set to false (or a falsy value such as `DEBUG=0`)

Comment: Locally : images in with Debug True, False, on, off, no DEBUG in .env
On heroku : images in with DEBUG set to True in env variables. When I change it to False, images dissapear.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it - I think it's because I am uploading files directly with the project? I read somewhere that you want to load media from s3 or other external sources?

I just tried bunch of DEBUG settings and the images just started showing no matter what I set in environment

Comment: Ok I don't really know why, but seems like images anyways show up. With debug 0 as well. What is the actual difference if you set debug to true or false? Is it only looking at allowed hosts?

Comment: But I think it has nothing to do with the debug variable. What I did just now was - 1. push to heroku 2. run collectstatic 3. Website works, but no images are displayed 4. Changed the environment var DEBUG from 0 to True - images started displaying 5. Changed DEBUG True to 0 and images are still OK.